# My beef stew vegetables taste like red wine vinegar

Tags: flavor

So apparently red wine and red wine vinegar for cooking are different and I didn’t know this. So for my beef stew I a cup of red wine vinegar instead of red wine (which I know nothing about wines either way) so now my vegetables taste terribly of vinegar. Is this fixable or should i toss it out? Please help

Comment: Baking soda can help but the problem is you added so much vinegar that the amount required will probably ruin the taste in other ways.  You can try adding in a pinch at a time and see where it goes but even for a big stew a full cup of vinegar is a MASSIVE amount.

Comment: The main issue is that while the reaction between vinegar and soda creates water and co2 (which are fine) it also creates sodium acetate, which is another sour flavor (used for salt and vinegar flavor chips).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to remove the vinegar taste. You can try augmenting it by sweetening the stew (using something more interesting than white sugar, as ChrisH points out in his answer) and adding warming spices, to move it in a [sauerbraten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauerbraten) direction. If this doesn’t appeal, throw it out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the vinegar accounts for a large proportion of the liquid you added. You mention one cup, but not how many servings or how much of everything else went in.  A cup is a huge amount for two servings, far less if it's meant to serve a dozen, though it could still taste quite vinegary.

I'd start by removing as much liquid as possible, by straining the stew.  Then replacing it with stock or water, perhaps with some grape or apple juice mixed in, and probably a little tomato puree/paste.

Sweetening as Sneftel suggests would be more interesting using treacle/molasses or honey than sugar - both are used in combination with vinegar to good effect.

But this is a lot of vinegar. If you don't manage to drain off enough you'll probably need to dilute it as well.  That would mean adding more of everything else, plus perhaps potato or pearl barley if they weren't already present.

Comment: Molasses, ginger, cloves, vinegar. It’s remarkable how many times this flavor combination has been independently discovered.

Comment: If one’s determined to save the stew with serious heroics, I’d also suggest removing as much of the vegetables as possible. Cheap to replace, will have absorbed the vinegar moreso than the meat, and further cooking would make them mushy.